# Scrapy 404 error: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed when scraping a webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a subreddit using Scrapy however, I keep getting 404 error every time I run the spider.

> 2020-01-07 12:21:46 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

The code I am currently using:

```
import scrapy 
class RedditbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Extracting the content using css selectors
        titles = response.css('.title.may-blank::text').extract()
        votes = response.css('.score.unvoted::text').extract()
        times = response.css('time::attr(title)').extract()
        comments = response.css('.comments::text').extract()

        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(titles,votes,times,comments):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'title' : item[0],
                'vote' : item[1],
                'created_at' : item[2],
                'comments' : item[3],
            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

I have tried rerunning after changing the USER_AGENT in the settings.py file however I have the same issue.

Comment: Are you using header while sending requests

Comment: I am not no, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you URL ... `http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//`(<- double slash)  as you wrote as your start url does not exist and throws a 404 error.